# how to insert a picture

Tags: graphics

I used previous comments and tried to insert an image in a very easy way, but I don''t know why it gives me errors and doesn't produce results. I have my picture in the same folder of .tex, but doesn't work.
here is the simplest code I use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{picture}

\end{document}
```

==========================

and here is the error:
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Looks from the error as though the image you're trying to include is corrupt. Note it says "no JPEG header found". Have you tried other images?

Comment: Off topic: Observe that blank lines in LaTeX have meaning(new paragraph), so do not make any, where they do not belong.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am happy I am here having you guys helping. You might be right, cause the format of my picture is .tiff and I had changed that to JPEG.
So does LaTeX knows .tiff?

Comment: I created a .PNG file (using Matlab) Torbjørn T, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: unrelated but `\center` is not intended to be used as a command like that, use `\centering`

Comment: @hpekristiansen while what you say is true there are no bad paragraph breaks in the example shown.

Comment: If you change `picture` to `example-image-a`, do you still get an error? If not, the problem is with the PNG produced by MatLab.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem solved. I appreciate your help. Now I am trying to continue my work, but I don't know how to give path to each picture.
let me be specific:
my .tex is in 'A' folder, and I have 40 different pictures in 40 different folders which these 40 folders are one folder back of folder 'A'. I do appreciate if you tell me how to do that.
thank you

Comment: Back is double point `\includegraphics{../FolderName/PictureName}`. If it's in a subfolder, it's `\includegraphics{./FolderName/PictureName}`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments.